# Store sent email from AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I want to store all the emails that are sent through SES. I think natively there is no support for this. Is there any way to do this like storing them in S3 or something?

Comment: Store where? In what format? In realtime? At what scale?

Comment: I just want to store the content(text data) of the emails that are sent using SES.

Comment: **Store where?** In DynamoDB? Anywhere?

Comment: S3 would be great but at this point whatever can solve it would be fine

Comment: I already saw this one, it is for storing inbound/received emails.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to store your sent emails in an S3 bucket.

SES offers [Configuraton Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets.html) which make possible to specify a destination to which Amazon SES will publish email sending events. Configuration Sets offer 3 types of destination which are SNS, CloudWatch and Kinesis Firestore.
From these ones, Kinesis Firestore has direct integration with S3, it can publish data to S3 in near-real time.

Pulling these all together, one solution for storing emails ins S3 would be the following:

1. Create a S3 bucket
2. Create a Firestore delivery stream which has the destination the S3 bucket created previously
3. Create a configuration set for the `Send` events and set the destination for this configuration set to be the Firestore delivery stream.

There is a reference tutorial from AWS which uses OpenSearch: [source](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-sending-history/). Instead using OpenSearch, you can use S3.

In order to use this configuration set when sending an email, you have to specify the following [header in the email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/using-configuration-sets-in-email.html): `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: ConfigSet`.

Example when sending a raw formatted email:

```
X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: myConfigurationSet
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Subject
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_boundary"

------=_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

body
------=_boundary
```